# Testing whether four points form a square in Haskell

Tags: haskell

On a website, I found the following challenge and got caught and I don't know how to solve it. We need to define the following function:

`isSquare :: (Num a, Ord a) => (a,a) -> (a,a) -> (a,a) -> (a,a) -> Bool`

Such that it returns True when the points are vertex of a square and False when they are not.

```
isSquare (1,1) (1,1) (1,1) (1,1)    == True
isSquare (0,0) (0,2) (3,2) (3,0)    == False
isSquare (0,0) (3,4) (8,4) (5,0)    == False
isSquare (0,0) (0,0) (1,1) (0,0)    == False
```

I have tried this:

1. Define a function that calculates the distance between points
2. Map `distance` to the list formated by points.
3. If the distances are equal, then `True`

Comment: What if they're out of order? e.g. do you want it to return True for (0,0), (1,1), (1,0), (0,1)? And do you want it to recognize squares that are not aligned with the coordinate axes?

Comment: You can't get distance between a list of points, you need a list of _pairs_ of points that are neighbors in the square.  Instead of enumerating what you tried how about you show the code and the error message in addition to telling us what part you can't figure out?

Comment: I don't know how to make the list of pairs of points? I get suck on this too

Comment: [Here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/1630/69655) is an answer on Programming Puzzles and Code Golf Stack Exchange that does this by counting the number of unique lengths when lengths are calculated pairwise.

Answer (score 3):

I'm sure there are a number of ways to solve this problem, but this is the first one that occurred to me.

```
import Data.Functor
import Data.Maybe
import Control.Applicative
import Control.Monad
```

First let's define a type for two-dimensional vectors and some basic operations on them. We're going to need to be able to add and subtract, and to use the dot product to test for orthogonality.

```
data V2 a = V2 a a
  deriving Eq

(^+), (^-) :: Num a => V2 a -> V2 a -> V2 a
V2 x y ^+ V2 x' y' = V2 (x + x') (y + y')
V2 x y ^- V2 x' y' = V2 (x - x') (y - y')
infixl 6 ^+, ^-

dotProduct :: (Num a) => V2 a -> V2 a -> a
dotProduct (V2 x y) (V2 x' y') = (x * x') + (y * y')

orthogonal :: (Eq a, Num a) => V2 a -> V2 a -> Bool
orthogonal a b = dotProduct a b == 0
```

And we'll also define a line segment:

```
data LineSegment a = LineSegment (V2 a) (V2 a)
```

The `isSquare` function is going to start by taking the first three points and seeing whether they form a right triangle. So let's define a right triangle type, and a function to turn three points into a right triangle if there is a right angle among them.

```
data RightTriangle a =
  RightTriangle
    (V2 a)          -- Point at the right angle
    (LineSegment a) -- Hypotenuse

rightTriangleMaybe :: (Eq a, Num a)
  => V2 a -> LineSegment a -> Maybe (RightTriangle a)
rightTriangleMaybe x hyp@(LineSegment a b) =
  guard (orthogonal (x ^- a) (x ^- b)) $> RightTriangle x hyp

rightTriangleMaybe' :: (Eq a, Num a)
  => V2 a -> V2 a -> V2 a -> Maybe (RightTriangle a)
rightTriangleMaybe' a b c =
  rightTriangleMaybe a (LineSegment b c) <|>
  rightTriangleMaybe b (LineSegment a c) <|>
  rightTriangleMaybe c (LineSegment a b)
```

Testing whether four points form a square now boils down to two steps:

1. Find the right angle among the first three points
2. Test whether the fourth point is in the right place

```
isSquare :: (Eq a, Num a) => V2 a -> V2 a -> V2 a -> V2 a -> Bool
isSquare a b c d = isJust $ do
  RightTriangle x (LineSegment y z) <- rightTriangleMaybe' a b c
  guard $ y ^+ z ^- x == d
```

(Try drawing a visual proof to see why the fourth point must lie at `y + z - x`)

Tests:

```
λ> isSquare (V2 0 1) (V2 1 0) (V2 0 (-1)) (V2 (-1) 0)
True

λ> isSquare (V2 0 1) (V2 1 0) (V2 0 (-1)) (V2 (-2) 0)
False

λ> isSquare (V2 0 1) (V2 1 0) (V2 0 0) (V2 1 1)
True

λ> isSquare (V2 0 1) (V2 1 0) (V2 0 0) (V2 1 2)
False

λ> isSquare (V2 3 4) (V2 3 4) (V2 3 4) (V2 3 4)
True

λ> isSquare (V2 3 4) (V2 3 4) (V2 3 4) (V2 3 5)
False
```

Comment: Please, don't define `Num` instances on non-number types like multidimensional vectors! This easily leads to strange bugs because multiplication and number literals have semantics that don't really make sense for vectors as mathematical objects. (Yes, I know Edward Kmett has done this mistake in `linear` as well... it has caused me some bugs that were almost Matlab-level weird.) Use [the purpose-intended class](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector-space-0.13/docs/Data-VectorSpace.html) instead.

Comment: @leftaroundabout Fair point. Updated to not use a class at all.

Comment: @leftaroundabout, you might appreciate [my recent PR](https://github.com/benl23x5/gloss/pull/39#event-1479449106) for `gloss`.

Answer (score 0):

If you have points p1, p2, p3 and p4 calculate the distances d1 =|p1 p2|, d2= |p1 p3|, d3 = |p1 p4|, d4 = |p2 p3|, d5 = |p2, p4|, d6 = |p3 p4|. (You can also compute the square of the distance...)

Look how many different distance values you got. If you have only 2 different values, then one is for the length of the 4 edges, the other for the length of the 2 diagonals and you have a square.

If you have more than 2 different values, it's not a square!

Hints for implementation: Create a list of the distances and then look at the list functions.

Comment: This check is not enough. e.g. let two congruent equilateral triangles share an edge and you will find there are only two different distance values between any pair of those four points, but they do not form a square. Another counterexample is to put a point at the center of an equilateral triangle. There may be others.

Answer (score 0):

We create a function that returns the cartesian distance between two points:

```
dist (x1, y1) (x2, y2) = sqrt $ (x2-x1)*(x2-x1)+(y2-y1)*(y2-y1)
```

From each point we can calculate distances to the three other points.

For a square, these distances will be the same for each of the points, and will have the form `[a, a, sqrt(2*a^2)]`. One can test for the following to establish that a given set of points form a square:

- all the distance lists are the same
- the shorter two distances are equal
- the longest distance = sqrt(2 * a^2) where a is the short distance

*in practice we don't need to establish the above conditions hold for all of the points, so you could chop a few lines from the following function*

```
import Data.List

isSquare (x1, y1) (x2, y2) (x3, y3) (x4, y4) =
  let m1 = dist (x1,y1)
      m2 = dist (x2,y2)
      m3 = dist (x3,y3)
      m4 = dist (x4,y4)
      d1 = sort $ map m1 [(x2,y2),(x3,y3),(x4,y4)]
      d2 = sort $ map m2 [(x1,y1),(x3,y3),(x4,y4)]
      d3 = sort $ map m3 [(x1,y1),(x2,y2),(x4,y4)]
      d4 = sort $ map m4 [(x1,y1),(x2,y2),(x3,y3)] 
  in d1 == d2 && d2 == d3 && d3 == d4 && d1!!0 == d1!!1 && sqrt((d1!!0)^2+(d1!!1)^2) == d1!!2
```

Here d1, d2, d3 & d4 are the sorted distance lists for each of the points

example:

for the square given by the points `(0,0) (0,1) (1,1) (1,0)`

the sorted distance list for point (0,0) is `[1,1,1.414]`

```
* distance to (0,1) = 1
* distance to (1,0) = 1
* distance to (1,1) = sqrt(2) ~ 1.414
```

similarly, the distance list for all the other points are `[1,1,1.414]`

We calculate the distance by mapping the partial distance functions over the lists, and then we sort so that the shorter distances are guaranteed to be at the head.

Then we can look into the distance lists and ensure that the first two elements are equal,

```
d1!!0 == d1!!1
```

and that the diagonal distance is equal to the square root of the squared sum of the two edge distances

```
sqrt((d1!!0)^2+(d1!!1)^2) == d1!!2
```

You can write this last condition equivalently as

```
(d1!!0)^2+(d1!!1)^2 == (d1!!2)^2
```

Actually, as user @dfeuer points out, we can use the squared distances for establishing a set of points is a square. Then, the functions can be written as

```
dist (x1, y1) (x2, y2) = (x2-x1)^2 + (y2-y1)^2

isSquare (x1,y1) (x2,y2) (x3,y3) (x4,y4) =
  let m1 = dist (x1,y1)
      m2 = dist (x2,y2)
      m3 = dist (x3,y3)
      m4 = dist (x4,y4)
      d1 = sort $ map m1 [(x2,y2),(x3,y3),(x4,y4)]
      d2 = sort $ map m2 [(x1,y1),(x3,y3),(x4,y4)]
      d3 = sort $ map m3 [(x1,y1),(x2,y2),(x4,y4)]
      d4 = sort $ map m4 [(x1,y1),(x2,y2),(x3,y3)]
  in d1 == d2 && d2 == d3 && d3 == d4 && d1!!0 == d1!!1 && 2*d1!!0 == d1!!2
```

Comment: I don't understand this: `d1!!0 == d1!!1 && sqrt((d1!!0)^2+(d1!!1)^2) == d1!!2`

Comment: And this: `d1 = sort $ map m1 [(x2,y2),(x3,y3),(x4,y4)]`

Comment: There's really no need to take square roots; that just makes the calculations less precise. You really only need the *squares* of the distances.